# Spark scala - Fetch column value based on column names defined in another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+                                        
|best_col     |A          |B              |  C   |<many more columns>  |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+
|     A#B     |    14     |        26     |  32  |       ...           |
|     C       |    13     |        17     |  96  |       ...           |
|     B#C     |    23     |        19     |  42  |       ...           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+
```

I want to end up with a DataFrame like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+----------+                                        
|best_col     |A          |B              |  C   |<many more columns>  | result   |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+----------+
|     A#B     |    14     |        26     |  32  |       ...           |   14#26  |
|     C       |    13     |        17     |  96  |       ...           |   96     |
|     B#C     |    23     |        19     |  42  |       ...           |   19#42  |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+---------------------+----------+
```

Essentially, I want to add a column `result` that will choose the value from the column specified in the `best_col` column. `best_col` only contains column names that are present in the DataFrame. I dont want to check like `col(best_col) === A` etc. I tried doing `col(col("best_col").toString())`, but this didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this fully dynamically but you can simply use a case when chain and list out all of the fields you can support (*) - clearly they must all have the same type. Your "I don't want to check like" is the only way, the AttributeReferences (column names) must be fixed for the duration of the query.

* If you are ok with building this when(col(bes_col) == "columnname") series of calls then you could use the schema to construct the fields that have the right type and get close to fully dynamic.

Comment: How can i create a when clause with all columns if column count is more than 1000

Comment: is your question how do I code such a thing (in which case use a list and foldLeft) or will it work with 1000?  The latter _may_ work, depending on the generated code size, if it hits 64k generated size it will fail and you may have to do two or more columns with the case's and nvl the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udf and pass whole row into it using withColumn. And depending on the value of column A, return the result.

Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

def concatFunc(row: Row) = ...
def combineUdf = udf((row: Row) => concatFunc(row))
```

And then use this:

```
df.withColumn("result", combineUdf(struct(columns.map(col): _*)))

// or try this as well if work
df.withColumn("result", combineUdf(*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution generating programmatically the appropriate when sequence:

```scala
// cols is the list of considered columns
val selection = cols
    .foldLeft(when(col("best_col").isNull, lit(null)))
             ((cur, column) => cur.when(col("best_col") === column, col(column)))

df.withColumn("result", selection).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Convert required columns into `map< key, value >` where key is column name & value is column value.
- Use `split` function on `best_col` column to split its values.
- Use `transform` higher order function, iterate over each key then look up & get value from `map<string, string>` data type.
- Use `concat_ws` to concat `array< value >`

Below is the sample code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- best_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- C: integer (nullable = false)
```

```
val columnsExpr = df.columns
  .map(c => col(c).as(c)) ++ Seq(
  df.columns
    .filter(_ != "best_col")
    .map(c => map(lit(c), col(c)))
    .reduce(map_concat(_, _))
    .as("map_data")
)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

columnsExpr: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(best_col AS best_col, A AS A, B AS B, C AS C, map_concat(map_concat(map(A, A), map(B, B)), map(C, C)) AS map_data)
```

```
val resultExpr =
  concat_ws(
       "#",
       transform(
          split($"best_col", "#"),
          t => col("map_data")(t)
       )
    )

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

resultExpr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = concat_ws(#, transform(split(best_col, #, -1), lambdafunction(map_data[x_20], x_20)))
```

```
scala> df
        .select(columnsExpr:_*)
        .show(false)

+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+
|best_col|A  |B  |C  |map_data                   |
+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+
|A#B     |14 |26 |32 |{A -> 14, B -> 26, C -> 32}|
|C       |13 |17 |96 |{A -> 13, B -> 17, C -> 96}|
|B#C     |23 |19 |42 |{A -> 23, B -> 19, C -> 42}|
+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
        .select(columnsExpr:_*)
        .withColumn("result", resultExpr)
        .show(false)

+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+------+
|best_col|A  |B  |C  |map_data                   |result|
+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+------+
|A#B     |14 |26 |32 |{A -> 14, B -> 26, C -> 32}|14#26 |
|C       |13 |17 |96 |{A -> 13, B -> 17, C -> 96}|96    |
|B#C     |23 |19 |42 |{A -> 23, B -> 19, C -> 42}|19#42 |
+--------+---+---+---+---------------------------+------+
```

**OR**

Below approach will convert all columns to `map<string, string>` type.

```
df
  .withColumn(
    "map_data",
    from_json(
        to_json(struct($"*")), 
        MapType(StringType, StringType)
    ) // Converting all columns to map<string, string>
  )
  .withColumn(
    "result",
    concat_ws(
      "#",
      transform(
        split($"best_col", "#"), // splitting best_col based on "#"
        t => col("map_data")(t)  // getting value from map data type & concating with #
      )
    )
  )
  .show(false)
```

**OR**

Use `udf`

```
scala> val concat_cols = udf( 
    (map: Map[String, String], data: String) => 
        data.split("#").map(c => map.getOrElse(c, null)).reduceOption(_ +"#"+ _)
    )

concat_cols: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = SparkUserDefinedFunction($Lambda$4451/448249168@34adac5b,StringType,List(Some(class[value[0]: map<string,string>]), Some(class[value[0]: string])),Some(class[value[0]: string]),None,true,true)

scala> df
    .withColumn("map_data", 
        from_json(
            to_json(
                struct($"*")
            ), 
            MapType(StringType, StringType)
        )
    )
    .withColumn("result", concat_cols($"map_data", $"best_col"))
    .show(false)
+--------+---+---+---+--------------------------------------------+------+
|best_col|A  |B  |C  |map_data                                    |result|
+--------+---+---+---+--------------------------------------------+------+
|A#B     |14 |26 |32 |{best_col -> A#B, A -> 14, B -> 26, C -> 32}|14#26 |
|C       |13 |17 |96 |{best_col -> C, A -> 13, B -> 17, C -> 96}  |96    |
|B#C     |23 |19 |42 |{best_col -> B#C, A -> 23, B -> 19, C -> 42}|19#42 |
+--------+---+---+---+--------------------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: We dont have transform function. Is there any alternate approach.

Comment: Why ? Any reason?

Comment: we are using spark 2

Comment: can we use udf for transform?

Comment: yes, updated solution. please check once

Answer (score 0):

Column "best_col" can be split, and for each other column technical column can be added, with null if column does not exists in "best_col"; and after columns joined with "concat_ws" function:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A#B", 14, 26, 32),
  ("C", 13, 17, 96),
  ("B#C", 23, 19, 42)).toDF("best_col", "A", "B", "C")

val withBestColumns = df.withColumn("best_columns", split($"best_col", "#"))

val columnNames = df.columns.tail
val withAdditionalFields = columnNames
  .foldLeft(withBestColumns) { case (df, columnName) => df.withColumn(columnName + "_required",
    when(array_contains($"best_columns", columnName),col(columnName).cast(StringType)).otherwise(null))
  }

val technicalColumnNames = columnNames.map(name=>name + "_required")

val result = withAdditionalFields
  .withColumn("result",  concat_ws("#", technicalColumnNames.map(col): _*))
  .drop(technicalColumnNames: _*)
  .drop("best_columns")
```

Result is:

```
+--------+---+---+---+------+
|best_col|A  |B  |C  |result|
+--------+---+---+---+------+
|A#B     |14 |26 |32 |14#26 |
|C       |13 |17 |96 |96    |
|B#C     |23 |19 |42 |19#42 |
+--------+---+---+---+------+
```